# Bash returning my variable empty in text file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line, sh

I'm trying to make simple bash which will find my IP and then update it in .txt template. When I ran bash I my file is filled with blank spot instead of IP address.

```
alias wanip='curl -s http://whatismijnip.nl |cut -d " " -f 5'
wanip
sed -i -e "s/\${ip}/"$wanip"/" config.txt
```

Comment: if `wanip` is an alias, what is `$wanip` supposed to be? Did you perhaps mean to run ``wanip`` (in backticks?) and substitute its output?

Comment: Please take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
wanip="$(curl -s http://whatismijnip.nl |cut -d " " -f 5)"
sed -i -e "s/\${ip}/"$wanip"/" config.txt
```

I suppose $ip is no variable.